# Lenovo Ideapad (Win 8) won't boot: No boot drive found

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, boot, bios, uefi

I have a Lenovo Ideapad that suddenly stopped booting. It falls to a screen saying

"No boot device found; Restart"

I can take it into the BIOS using F2 and there under the Information Tab it does show an HDD as "ST500LT012-1DG142"

But if I go to the Boot Tab of the BIOS the "UEFI Boot priority order" has no devices listed under it at all.

Other settings:
Boot Mode-UEFI
USB Boot-Enabled
Secure Boot-Enabled
SATA Controller Mode-Compatible

Any thoughts about how I can fix this?

I tried toggling many of these BIOS settings but doesn't seem to fix it. If I change the BOOT Mode to "Legacy" the HDD appears in the Boot list but the laptop still won't boot.

It stops at the same screen saying "No boot device found"

Comment: On Lenovo devices, pressing F12 immediately after powering on the device typically takes you to the boot device selection menu.   How you tried that?

Comment: Thanks! Tried that. But the HDD does not show up there at all. Rest of the laptop is fine. I can successfully run a live USB Linux off it.